# How do I call a heading as an argument when defining a function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
   Major        Sample_size   Men   Women  ShareWomen  Employed    ...     Part_time
   Economics    36            2057  282    0.120564    1976        ...     270   
   French       7             679   77     0.101852    640         ...     170
```

And I'm trying to define a function as follows:

```
def cutoff(category, cut, direction):

    if direction == 0:
        comply = list(zip(df[df.category < cut].Major, df[df.category < cut].category))

    if direction == 1:
        comply = list(zip(df[df.category > cut].Major, df[df.category > cut].category))       

    return comply
```

Where `category` is meant to refer to the variable of interest (e.g. `Men` or `Employed` or `Part_time`). But I cannot seem to call `category` as an input variable in this way. How would one go about doing so?

Comment: what's your data frame? Pandas?

Comment: you should add all relevant tags in your question, in this case at least [tag:pandas] too

Comment: @Daniel Yes, Pandas.

Comment: And thanks, @AnttiHaapala. I'm new to StackOverflow and am still in the tinkering stages of using Python and Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `df[category]`

```
def cutoff(category, cut, direction):

    if direction == 0:
        comply = list(zip(df[df[category] < cut].Major, df[df[category] < cut][category]))

    if direction == 1:
        comply = list(zip(df[df[category] > cut].Major, df[df[category] > cut][category]))  

    return comply
```

Comment: This works great! Should have been obvious in retrospect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can access panda frames by attributes or items. Attributes must be known at coding time, items must be strings and therefore can be variables.

```
df.Major
```

vs.

```
df['Major']
```

I would suggest, to separate cut off and conversion to list:

```
def cutoff(df, category, cut, direction):
    mask = df[category] < cut if direction == 0 else df[category] > cut
    return df[mask]

def get_list(df, category):
    return list(zip(df.Major, df[category]))

get_list(cutoff(df, 'Employed', 1000, 1))
```